# What are the steps to be followed for enabling Internet after installing Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

After installing Ubuntu 18.04, the system is not showing WLAN and network option. Is this the normal behavior?

"No WiFi device found" on WiFi settings.

What should be done to enable Internet in my system?

System details: Dell 5420 i7 laptop

Edit: Result for `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`
[image]

Result for:

> rfkill list

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
         softblocked: no
         hardblocked: no
```

Adding result for `lshw -C network`:

[image]

Comment: No that is not normal. For some wifi cards, you might need some additional drivers. Check [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en). Just out of curiosity, why do you install an almost 4 year old version of Ubuntu? It's still supported, but still there are newer versions.

Comment: @pLumo Thanks for the response. I am checking the link here. Actually it's a company laptop, OS was installed by the system team. Think they were not having the latest version, if the steps not working, planning to install latest version by myself.

Comment: The first step is to identify the exact wireless device. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Comment: @chili555 Pls see the suggested command's result.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for the link, checking it, but most of the answers are pointing to download some script. But my wired LAN is also not working.

Comment: Install 20.04 and all should work by itself.

Comment: "Install 20.04 and all should work by itself" Yes, indeed! You have very new hardware and installed a relatively old version of Ubuntu. Please try a live session of 20.04.3 and I'm confident that the wireless will work. If it does, install it and be happy!

Comment: Please copy/paste and format text instead of pictures of text. A picture (of text) can't be read on a text-only terminal, can't be copied from (edited, tried, and made to work), AND makes one take an action to even read your Question. Since we're all volunteers, some won't click. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I installed 20.04 and now it's working fine. Commenting from the same system :)